# Residue at infinity calculating integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the following problem which I want to evaluate at infinity:
$$\oint \dfrac{(z+2)}{(z^2+9)}dz$$

I approach this problem by saying that $z=\dfrac{1}{t}$ and $dz=\dfrac{-1}{t^2}dt$. And I plug them inside my integral and obtain:
$$\oint \dfrac{-(2t+1)}{(t+9t^3)}dz=-2\pi i Res(0)=-2\pi i$$
Yet this result is not in accordance with the usual integration using residues which yield $2\pi i$. I was wondering where am I doing a mistake of minus.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate at infinity"?  $\oint$ generally means an integral around a contour.  What contour?

Comment: I was trying to imply when z goes to infinity.

Comment: Note that 0 is not the only point where your new function has poles, in fact it has poles at $1/3i$ and $-1/3i$ which is worse than the original, so I don't understand the point of the change of variables. Also by "going to infinity" do you mean evaluating the contour integral for a circle whose radius goes to infinity?

Comment: The residue at $\infty$ being $-1$ is the correct result.  You can also check with this: the sum of residues should be $0$.  The residues at $\pm 3\text{i}$ are $\frac{1}{2}\mp \frac{1}{3}\text{i}$, which sum to $1$.  Hence, the residue at $\infty$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to evaluate the integral,$\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z+2}{z^2+9}\,dz$, after making the transformation $z\mapsto 1/z$, we can proceed as follows.

For $R>3$, we have for $z\mapsto 1/z$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z+2}{z^2+9}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=1/R}\frac{1+2z}{z(1+9z^2)}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1+2z}{z(1+9z^2)},z=0 \right)\\\\
&=2\pi i 
\end{align}$$

as expected.

Recall that under the transformation, $dz\mapsto -\frac1{z^2}\,dz$ and the contour is traversed clockwise.

Comment: I was interested why the contour is trasvered clockwise actually. I assume because $z=e^{i\alpha}$ and $t=e^{-i\beta}$ so it causes the negative sign.

Comment: Indeed.  You have it.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want $\displaystyle \oint_\Gamma \dfrac{z+2}{z^2+9} \; dz$ where $\Gamma$ is a positively oriented contour near $\infty$ (i.e. outside the poles at $z = \pm 3 i$), the simplest thing to do is consider the start of the Laurent series near $\infty$:

$$ \dfrac{z+2}{z^2+9} = \dfrac{z+2}{z^2} (1 - 9/z^2 + \ldots) = \frac{1}{z} -\frac{7}{z^2} + \ldots $$

so the result is $2\pi i$.